# How to detect app force quit event in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I am working on an iOS app for which I need to show a **local notification** when users force quit the application.

I tried to use the "**applicationWillTerminate**" iOS callback but it doesn't work when the app is killed from the **multi-tasking** window.

From the official Apple documentation, it appears that there is no way to detect the force quit app event (from the multi-tasking window) but I found that [Alarmy](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/alarmy-wake-up-alarm-clock/id1163786766) app can show a notification when we force quit the application.

Questions:

1. How this "Alarmy" app can show the force-quit app notification? What possible approach is used by the application?
2. Are there any workaround solutions for this problem?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: "applicationWillTerminate" delegate does call when we terminate app from anywhere.

Comment: Thank you @VikasRajput. But the "applicationWillTerminate" delegate doesn't call if your app is suspended.

Comment: Alarmy's FQ notification has a slight delay; I wonder if this is a key, i.e. dispatching to a different queue. Also, you may have noticed that this isn't a remote push - it works in airplane mode and there is no "Background App Refresh" option for the app that comes with the Push Notifications capability.

Comment: Tesla app does this too. There must be a way

Answer (score -1):

The way to use local notifications to notify you if the app is terminated is by constantly scheduling and canceling local push notifications.  For example, while the app is running it will schedule a push to happen in one minute.  Shortly before that notification is supposed to be sent, the app will cancel it, and then schedule a new one, one more minute in the future.  If the app is quit, then it will be unable to cancel the notification, and it will be sent.

This will cause the notification to be sent if the user force quits the app or the operating system terminates the app.

Answer (score -3):

When app terminates, the following delegate will be called:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)app
{
}
```

To receiving the terminate event, you need to add the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key to your `info.plist`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If you add the "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend" key, my app will terminate as soon as I put the app in the background. I want my app to work in the background. Hence, adding the key is a desirable solution.